# Insert code from Method into new class

Tags: java, kotlin, byte-buddy

I'm trying to make a library on top of bytebuddy that can be used to perform runtime transformations on a class. The API that I'm making isn't directly operable with ByteBuddy to insert method code into transformed classes, (I want unannotated methods to be added brand new to the transformed class, and methods annotated with `@Inject` to be injected into the head or tail of an existing method), My solution to the lack of interoperability was to create a temporary class using ByteBuddy, that transforms between my higher level API, and the Advice API from ByteBuddy. But I can't figure out how I could insert all the code from a method in the higher level API into methods defined in the lower level one, since I can't actually use Advice to do it. Is there a way I could do this?

This is the code that I've come up with to this point

```
fun apply(vararg transformerClasses: Class<*>) {
    for(clazz in transformerClasses) {
        val builder = ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(clazz)
        val mixinAnnotation = clazz.getAnnotation(Mixin::class.java) as? Mixin ?: throw RuntimeException("Passed transformer class without @Mixin annotation")
        val mixinTarget = mixinAnnotation.target.java

        for(method in clazz.declaredMethods) {
            if(method.annotations.isEmpty()) {
                builder.defineMethod(method.name, method.returnType, Visibility.PUBLIC, Ownership.STATIC)
                        .intercept(???)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please point out the actual problem a little bit better. Thx

Comment: I can't directly pass annotated methods from my API to Bytebuddy's Advice API to insert them into a new classfile. I need to figure out how to insert the code from those methods into a class

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a good way to do so but one solution would be to creste a `TypeDescription` instance where you translate your custom annotations to those of Byte Buddy.
You could use an implementation of `InstrumentedType` for creating such an object.

Byte Buddy still reads the byte code from the correct class file if the class name matches. There is no consistency check between the class file and the type description.